# While duplicating cards it becoms darker & hr tag placeing independetly

Tags: html, css

I have a issue with duplicating my cards, every time when i duplicate my card the card color getting darker see the picture ->:

[image]

I mean the green and the purple are getting darker from left to right (float:left) why is this happening?

Im giving my html and css codes as well here:

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yeni6c.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="aussen">
    <div class="in_card">
        <div class="in_up">
            <!-- <hr> -->
            <div class="total center">TOTAL
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="in_down">
            <div class="number center">NUMBER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="in_card two">
        <div class="in_up">
            <!-- <hr> -->
            <div class="total center">TOTAL2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="in_down">
            <div class="number center">NUMBER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="in_card tree">
        <div class="in_up">
            <!-- <hr> -->
            <div class="total center">TOTAL3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="in_down">
            <div class="number center">NUMBER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="in_card four">
        <div class="in_up">
            <hr>
            <div class="total center">TOTAL4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="in_down">
            <div class="number center">NUMBER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**MY CSS CODE**

```
.aussen {

    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #F5A9BC;
    background: #FBEFF2;
}

.center {

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.in_card {

    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*.in_card.zwei {

}*/

.in_card .in_up {

    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}

.in_card .in_down {

    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: purple;
}

.in_card .in_down .number {

    text-align: center;

}

.in_card .in_up .total {

    text-align: center;
}

.aussen hr {

    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 60px;

}
```

where is my mistake so that gets darker here?

-> My second question is, how can I a `<hr>` tag make independetly I mean look at the card TOTAL3 and TOTAL4 there is difference if I place a `<hr>` tag in the middle of two collors, the text TOTAL4 is moving I dont want that but I want still place my `<hr>` tag relativ to my main card `class="in_card"`.

I hope i explained everything good and someone can help me :)

Comment: In your picture the colors are not getting darker. I checked with Gimp,  green is ```#008000``` and purple is ```#800080``` for each of the four cards.

Comment: oh.. i thing my eyes are just bad than  :) thank you... Can you maybe answer my second question?